# Algorithm to group characters together in string

Tags: algorithm, sorting, grouping

I am looking for an algorithm that will group together characters in a string. For example:

If we have this string:

```
ghfgjggjhfjfjgjghghhf
```

The program might output:

```
hhhhhgggggggffffjjjjj
```

The characters **do not have to be sorted**, only grouped together.

Is there an algorithm or class of algorithms that are designed to do this?

Comment: Any particular programming language?  That may have an impact on the suggested approach

Comment: Why not count frequency of each character and then just rewrite the original string?

Comment: A [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) would probably be the most efficient approach.

Comment: "The characters do not have to be sorted, only grouped together." I do not understand this line tbh. Wouldn't sort also group your string in this particular case? Or maybe it's about complexity?

Comment: @ulou In my case, the string does not need to be sorted, but the program has to be as fast as possible. Therefore, it seems like a waste of processing power to sort everything if I only need to group it.

Comment: @Martin No particular programming language.

Comment: Counting the number of occurrences of each character might be a theoretical best algorithm, but for most datasets it's highly likely that using the programming language's default sorting function will actually be faster. You'd need to run benchmarks with your data to be sure.

Comment: If speed is an important consideration, it may make more sense to treat this as an array of bytes instead of a string, and then process the bytes instead.  Of course then you need to consider multi-byte character encoding (utf8, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count all occurrences (complexity `O(n)`), then you create `string` from those counts by repeating every `char` of his occurrence (complexity `O(n)`, probably even better - something like `(O(n/26)`, it's up to `chars` uniqueness). For long strings, that might be better than simply `sort`.

Example:

```js
const input = "ghfgjggjhfjfjgjghghhf"

const count = [...input].reduce(
  (acc, char) => ({
      ...acc,
      [char]: (acc[char] ? acc[char] + 1 : 1)
  }),
  {}
)

const res = Object.entries(count)
                  .reduce((acc, [char, count]) => acc + char.repeat(count), "")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If output does not need to be sorted you'd typically build a frequency map to hold the `count` of each character, which is then repeated `count` times in the output.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```java
String s = "ghfgjggjhfjfjgjghghhf";

Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
for(char c : s.toCharArray())
    m.put(c, 1 + m.getOrDefault(c, 0));

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : m.keySet())
    for(int i=m.get(c); i>=0; i--)
        b.append(c);
System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

```
fffffgggggggghhhhhhjjjjjj
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, you can achieve this by:

1. Splitting the source string into an array of characters
2. Sorting the array of characters
3. Joining the array of characters into a single string

See the following working snippet:

```js
source = "ghfgjggjhfjfjgjghghhf";
sourceArray = source.split("");
outArray = sourceArray.sort();
output = outArray.join("");
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
ffffggggggghhhhhjjjjj
```

Note that because of the use of `.sort()`, the characters are actually sorted alphabetically.  In your question you state that it doesn't matter how it's sorted as long as the characters are grouped.

Also here's some quick Python to use the same approach:

```
source = 'ghfgjggjhfjfjgjghghhf'
print(''.join(sorted(source)))
```

I see in the comments that you are looking for the most efficient way to achieve this.  I suspect my suggestion here is *not* efficient because of the expense of converting the answers into arrays of characters and back again.